# how to solve " call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback "

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi my site wordpress if there is No attribute entered  " call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback " issue show in product page But if i chose attributes it is working fine , my code is :

```
<?php
        if (!empty($tabs)) :
            $k_tab = $comboContent ? 1 : 0;
            foreach ($tabs as $key => $tab) :
                ?>
                <div class="nasa-panel entry-content<?php echo ($k_tab == 0) ? ' active' : ''; ?>" id="nasa-tab-<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>">
                    <?php if ($key == 'description' && $specifi_desc): ?>
                        <div class="nasa-panel-block">
                            <?php  call_user_func($tab['callback'], $key, $tab); ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if (trim($specifications) != '') : ?>
                            <div class="nasa-panel-block nasa-content-specifications">
                                <?php echo $specifications; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php
                    
                         
                   else:
                           call_user_func($tab['callback'], $key, $tab);
                   endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
                if ($key == 'description' && (trim($specifications) != '') && !$specifi_desc) : ?>
                    <div class="nasa-panel entry-content nasa-content-specifications" id="nasa-tab-specifications">
                        <p><?php echo $specifications; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                endif;
                $k_tab++;
            endforeach;
       
        endif;
```

[image: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback]

could please help me